# exchange 2010 validate FROM field against the GAL for anonymous SMTP

Tags: smtp, exchange-server-2010

I have several applications sending email (anonymous SMTP) thru an exchange 2010 server via a dedicated receive connector. I would like the exchange server to validate the FROM field against the GAL before accepting the message : if the sender is in the GAL, the message is accepted, if not in the GAL, the message is rejected.

I found no way of doing this. any idea ?

TIA,
Pierre